# Cygwin absolute path give C://cygdrive/c while relative path works fine

Tags: cygwin

Using VScode CLI *(code)* with relative path works fine with cygwin:
`code ../source`

but using absolute path it gives me something that starts with `C://cygdrive/c/...`:

`code ~/source` gives me `C://cygdrive/c/Users/user/source`.

This path does not exist, so I create a new file.

How can I make cygwin work with absolute paths?

*VScode in PATH looks like this: `/cygdrive/c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that VScode (windows side) gets `C:\cygdrive\c\Users\user\source` and tries to resolve it. This leads to file not found so we create a new one in that path.

I solved it on the windows side by creating a symbolic link between `C:\cygdrive\c\` with `C:\`.

1. I create an empty folder on `C` named `cygdrive`.
2. I open **cmd** as admin.
3. I execute the command `mklink /D "C:\cygdrive\c\" "C:\"`.

and VScode runs as expected.

Answer (score 1):

VScode on Windows probably does not expect nor properly interpret POSIX-style paths.  `/cygdrive/c/...` is an absolute path from the Cygwin perspective (by default Cygwin mounts your Windows drive letters under `/cygwin/`).

But to VScode (or other native Windows applications) this does not look like an absolute path, so it will prepend `C:\something\...` to it to make it absolute.

As with most path issues related to using native Windows applications on Cygwin, you should use the `cygpath` utility to convert your path to one VScode can understand.  E.g.

```
$ code "$(cygpath -w -a ~/source)"
```

See [Using Cygwin effectively with Windows](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html).

Comment: This solution works too but it is not as flexible because i would need a function like this for every command i would need to take absolute paths

Comment: Yep, you can make a bash alias or something. In some applications it will Just Work even without but it's hit-or-miss. As you can see in the link I provided this is the way. There's not going to be a magic solution.